# How to get a list of VM SKUs only that support AKS hosting

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-aks, sku

I am aware of the command, **az vm list-skus --location** , which gives us a list of all VM SKUs in a specific location but I would like to have that list filtered which shows only the VM SKUs supported by the AKS hosting.

Can someone please assist? It is kinda important. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quick way to do this. There was a [GitHub Issue from 2018](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/147) regarding "List supported node-vm-sizes" but it had not been resolved.

I checked myself while creating an AKS cluster whether tab completion will work or not. You can try hitting Tab after **az aks create -l westeurope -s** .

[image: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/147]

But it seems that it still does not work. "Standard_A1" should not be used according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quotas-skus-regions#restricted-vm-sizes).

> **Restricted VM sizes**
>
> VM sizes with less than 2 CPUs may not be used with AKS.
>
> Each node in an AKS cluster contains a fixed amount of compute
> resources such as vCPU and memory. If an AKS node contains
> insufficient compute resources, pods might fail to run correctly. To
> ensure the required kube-system pods and your applications can be
> reliably scheduled, **AKS requires nodes use VM sizes with at least 2
> CPUs**.